# How lambda inside JSX works?

Tags: javascript, lambda, jsx

In [React Final Form examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/z2zqr008pm) I can see a construct:

```
<ErrorWithDelay name="firstName" delay={1000}>
    {error => <span>{error}</span>}
</ErrorWithDelay>
```

What it this lambda inside JSX? How it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is passed to the `ErrorWithDelay` function as the `children` property name, as you can see from:

```
const ErrorWithDelay = ({ name, children, delay }) => (
```

The `children` property is the same expression as the function expression inside `ErrorWithDelay`, specifically:

```
error => <span>{error}</span>
```

The `ErrorWithDelay` component can then decide whether and when to invoke it. In this case, it's only invoked if there's an error:

```
return error && ((touched && !active) || (touched && !show && active) || show)
  ? children(error)
  : null
```

If there's no error, `null` will be returned, so there won't be any text there.

Answer (score 1):

It is a design pattern in React, called [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

> The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between React components using a prop whose value is a function.

It works due to the fact that the parent of this lambda invoking it and passing some inner state to it.

A rule of thumb of my for using this design pattern is when you have a common logic but it can be rendered in a different way, so the common logic will be in the parent component, that will receive `children` prop as a function, and that function will return elements.

Like in your case, `ErrorWithDelay` has some error handling logic inside of it, and it doesn't know how to render it, the user of the component defines how it will render (in your case as a `span`).

For more design patterns, checkout egghead course Kent C. Dodds, https://egghead.io/lessons/react-course-overview-advanced-react-component-patterns